# How do I specify Map or List properties in JHipster JDL?

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

I've just started using JHipster to jumpstart a new Java/Spring Boot application.  The new application needs to replicate entities and services from an existing app.  One of the entities has List and Map properties:
`List<String> tagCodes = new ArrayList<>()`
`Map<String, String> targetSystems = new HashMap<>()`
The JDL domain language that is part of JHipster understands a number of scalar types, but I don't see a way of representing (and thereby generating code for) properties which are Lists and Maps.  Any suggestions?

Comment: These types are not supported in JDL, you must code it manually and the solution may depend on which database you use.